# On demand image display using JQuery sample needed

Tags: jquery

today i visit a site and saw that when i scroll down then images are getting fetch from server and being visible. 
the site url is http://www.ajaxshake.com/en/JS/12611/list-of-pagination-scripts.html.
please have look at the site and scroll down then u will see the effect that load images at run time when user scroll down.

please tell me someone how could i do this. i need a site url from where i will get exact sample using jquery. please let me know if anyone have knowledge for the effect.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a working example (not mine):
http://www.dustindiaz.com/element-scroll-into-view/
It's not jquery but javascript is ok too, I guess.